# Stacking divs vertically using flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**[WEBSITE TO REVIEW](https://www.sorensonvrs.com/index_cl)**

Im trying to get the orange bar to stack underneath the sliding banner images WHEN the BROWSER is RESIZED (responsive), but images are moving behind the orange bar. It seems the Flexbox is not working. I have 2 group of divs set to stack vertically in HTML when responsive.

This is the example I need on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/n79sg1kh/13/)**

**This is screenshot below is what I need -**

[image]

HTML -

```
<div class="main-container">
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/ntouchdesktop"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_2.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://www.sorenson.com/wavello" target="_blank"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_1.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/ntouchmobile"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_5.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/ntouchdesktop"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_6.png"></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/ntouchmobile"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_3.png" ></a></div>
    <div id="liSlider"><a href="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/ntouchmobile"><img src="https://qasvrs.sorensonaws.com/assets/images/svrsv2/SVRS_Homepage-Slide_4.png"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="fp-container1">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;"> 
        <div style="background-color: #ffbb11; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px 0 20px 0;">
            <div style="width: 75%; margin: 0 auto;"><h2 style="color: #353735; font-size: 2.2em;">Coronavirus Update</h2></div>
            <div class="fp-button_2" id="fp-button_2-signup" style="background-color: #fff; top: -15px; width: 185px;"><a style="line-height: 1.4 !important;" href="#">MORE INFO</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#slideshow {
  height: 500px;
}
#slideshow img {
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 85px;
  left: 0;
}
.main-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 527px;
}
```

Comment: I think `flex-direction: column;` is what you are looking for.

.main-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  ...
}

Comment: `display` is duplicated on `.main-container`. `display: block` is overriding `display: flex`.

Comment: I added `flex-direction: column;` and removed `display: block` and still doesnt work.

Comment: Anybody help here?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that the images in your slider are not loaded. The slider is working, but the image sources are not received from the server. Maybe if you fix this, it will be easier to debug.

And regarding the flexbox layout, you can test the following and see if it matches the requirements:

```
// Leave only these styles for the slideshow
#slideshow {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;   // Just an example height
}

Remove this rule: 
.main-container > * {
 flex: 0 0 100%
}
```

The `300px` height only demonstrates the elements layout, you will have to adjust it as in the design.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the rule of css you suggested and changed the `#slideshow` css. It still doesnt work. By the way, the images loads OK and its working.

Comment: I fixed the height to `height: 500px;`, but when you resize the browser the images moves behind the orange bar. The orange bar should be following the images' size whenever the browser is resized smaller or larger. When its smaller, you can see the white gap underneath the images.

Comment: The white gap is there, because `.fp-container1` is hidden on smaller screens. You have a media query that affects it below 879px. The devtools shows this at your `fp_media.css` line 61. Remove it and the orange bar will be visible again.

Comment: Thank you - Dimitar. That didnt work, but I dont think thats the problem. [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/n79sg1kh/12/) - this is what I need whenever the browser is resized.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be giving the issue which are you facing.

```
.main-container > * {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Remove this and you should be good to go. Also give a height to the `#slideshow` as images takes time to load

Example:

```
#slideshow{
   height:300px 
}
```

Comment: Updated and its still doesnt work. Im not understanding why the divs are not stacked together as I've hoped. Going to upload the update in a few mins...

Comment: I fixed the height to `height: 500px;`, but when you resize the browser the images moves behind the orange bar. The orange bar should be following the images' size whenever the browser is resized smaller or larger. When its smaller, you can see the white gap underneath the images.